# Three.js load FBX and Materials locally from input file

Tags: three.js

From a few days i'm trying to load an .fbx file with materials locally from input file but without success.
I have found this code that works with collada file, i have changed it to works with .fbx but notthing...

```
$("#campoFile3dNascosto").change(function (e) {
    var files = e.currentTarget.files;
    var dae_path;

    var extraFiles = {}, file;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        file = files[i];
        extraFiles[file.name] = file;

        //Filename ends in .dae/.DAE
        if (files[i].name.match(/\w*.dae\b/i)) {
            dae_path = files[i].name;
        }
    }

    const manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
    manager.setURLModifier(function (url, path) {

        url = url.split('/');
        url = url[url.length - 1];

        if (extraFiles[url] !== undefined) {

            var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(extraFiles[url]);
            console.log("blob: "+blobURL); //Blob location created from files selected from file input
            return blobURL;

        }
        return url;
    });


    var loader = new THREE.FBXLoader(manager);
    loader.load(dae_path, function (object) {
       object.traverse(function (child) {
            if (child.isMesh) {
                child.castShadow = true;
                child.receiveShadow = true;
            }
        });
    });

});
```

How can i do that?

Comment: I'm not sure this is relevant but you still have Collada specifc code in our listing. `(files[i].name.match(/\w*.dae\b/i)) {` should be probably `(files[i].name.match(/\w*.fbx\b/i)) {`.

Comment: Instead, that was the problem! thank you!